# Win32_PnPSignedDriver only have 5 properties

Tags: windows, wmi

I have some problem with querying the `Win32_PnPSignedDriver`.

Here is the code that i use to querying the `PnPSignedDriver` properties.

```
string query = "Select * from Win32_PnPSignedDriver";
tbLog.Clear();

ManagementObjectSearcher objSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( "root\\CIMV2", query );
ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = objSearcher.Get();
var managementObject = objCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
PropertyDataCollection props = managementObject.Properties;
foreach ( PropertyData prop in props )
{
    tbLog.AppendText( String.Format( "Property name: {0}\r\n", prop.Name ) );
}
```

When I run the query on my computer, the result is:

> Property name: Caption
>  
>   Property name: ClassGuid
>  
>   Property name: CompatID
>  
>   Property name: CreationClassName
>  
>   Property name: Description
>  
>   Property name: DeviceClass
>  
>   Property name: DeviceID
>  
>   Property name: DeviceName
>  
>   Property name: DevLoader
>  
>   Property name: DriverDate
>  
>   Property name: DriverName
>  
>   Property name: DriverProviderName
>  
>   Property name: DriverVersion
>  
>   Property name: FriendlyName
>  
>   Property name: HardWareID
>  
>   Property name: InfName
>  
>   Property name: InstallDate
>  
>   Property name: IsSigned
>  
>   Property name: Location
>  
>   Property name: Manufacturer
>  
>   Property name: Name
>  
>   Property name: PDO
>  
>   Property name: Signer
>  
>   Property name: Started
>  
>   Property name: StartMode
>  
>   Property name: Status
>  
>   Property name: SystemCreationClassName
>  
>   Property name: SystemName

But when i ran the same code on the production machine the result is:

> Property name: DriverDate
>   Property name: DriverDesc
>  
>   Property name: DriverVersion
>   Property name: Index
>   Property
>   name: ProviderName

Does anyone know why I have 2 different results? 
Does this means that the WMI is corrupt and I need to rebuild the WMI on the production machine?

Thanks,
Fitriadi

Comment: `objCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault()` What happens if you look beyond the first one?

Comment: It's the same result, only 5 Properties returned